# HTML: Create a combobox-style control

Tags: html, css

How can I create a text field inside a select tag of HTML forms.

I have tried

```
<form>

<select>
<option> <input type="text"/> </option>
<option> myname </option>
<option> yourname </option>

</select>

</form>
```

But this ain't working.. Any clues please ?

For an example, see this website http://petsplusus.com/quote/pet the pet breed field

Comment: That's because you can't do that. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: That's a custom control that *looks* like a text input inside a select, but that's not what it really is.

Comment: This is done with javascript, view their source for clues. Or better yet learn HTML, it's quite useful if you want to build a web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not valid have a input inside a option of a select, but what people do is create a custom select where you can have a search box inside it, you can use a little plugin to do that, here it is [Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an `input` inside of an `<option>` tag. That's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `input` tag inside an `select/option`. Because:

- Is invalid HTML;
- Doesn't make any sense

Comment: Make sense if you trying to put a search box inside the select box

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an input inside an  tag.
Instead you must do something like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="dog">dog</option>
  <option value="cat">cat</option>
</select>
```

Please check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a textbox inside a dropdown.

You can put the textbox outside the dropdown, and only show it when a specific option is selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function settext(sel) {
  if (sel.selectedIndex == 1) {
    document.getElementById('txt').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('txt').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>

<select onchange="settext(this);">
  <option> custom name: </option>
  <option> myname </option>
  <option> yourname </option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txt" style="display:block" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to create a combobox.

jQuery UI has an [autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) that can do this for you. If you're not using jQuery or jQuery UI, Googling "combobox" can get you started in the right direction.